# Getting error while creating hive table using "hive -e" but not in hive shell

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to create hive table on top of HBase table. Using the mentioned query for same.

```
create external table MaprDB_batch_info_table (Batch_ID string, BatchParserJobId string, count string, CurrentRunTime string) 

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe' STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,BatchInfo:BatchParserJobId,BatchInfo:count,BatchInfo:CurrentRunTime") TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = '/user/all/batchinfo');
```

This command is successfully executing in hive shell but when I try to execute same through bash shell

```
hive -e "create external table MaprDB_batch_info_table (Batch_ID string, BatchParserJobId string, count string, CurrentRunTime string) 

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe' STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,BatchInfo:BatchParserJobId,BatchInfo:count,BatchInfo:CurrentRunTime") TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = '/user/all/batchinfo');
```

I get below error:

> NoViableAltException(26@[])
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tablePropertiesList(HiveParser.java:34375)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableProperties(HiveParser.java:34243)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.tableFileFormat(HiveParser.java:35913)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:5380)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2640)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1650)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:397)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:309)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1146)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1194)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1083)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1073)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:311)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:708)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>   FAILED: ParseException line 1:473 cannot recognize input near 'hbase' '.' 'columns' in table properties list'

If anybody can help in rectifying this please.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `"` that you have within the query with `'`

```
...('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,BatchInfo:BatchParserJobId,BatchInfo:count,BatchInfo:CurrentRunTime')...
```

Also you have an issue with the value given to `'hbase.table.name'`, replace the path with the actual table name.